# How use static_cast with double casting

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

How can I use static_cast with casting types like that:

```
CString response;
resultData = (void *) (const char *) response;
```

where result data is type `void *&`.

I tried to do to this in following way:

```
resultData = static_cast<(void*)(const char*)>(response);
resultData = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<const char*>(response));
```

but it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Use `const_cast`

Comment: watch out because undefined behavior is knocking to your door

Comment: Are you sure you can convert a `CString` to a pointer with a cast?

Comment: @moooeeeep it's ugly as hell, but, const cast aside, yes you can ( because Microsoft says so, see msdn for more details )

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Didn't find an overload for `operator const char*()` however: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class ... am I looking at the wrong page?

Comment: @moooeeeep the ugliest thing is that they don't even need a conversion  operator ( but there is one to CSimpleStringT that in turn convert to const char* ): I've seen them used also for things like printf or qsort; quoting from the page you linked, "You can freely substitute CStringT objects for PCXSTR function arguments. "

Comment: Isnt `void *&` equal to `void` ?

Comment: @moooeeeep - Originally `CString` just happened to "work" with `printf("%s",` as it stored a `char*` as its first member. This was by chance. Later Microsoft has changed this from UB to implementation defined in order not to break half the world. So casting `CString` to `const char*` works, now by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to cast to `const void *`:

```
resultData = static_cast<const void*>(static_cast<const char*>(response));
```

Or you need to use `const_cast` (which is needed to remove `const`, `static_cast` cannot remove it):

```
resultData = static_cast<void*>(const_cast<char *>(static_cast<const char*>(response)));
```

Note: if your `resultData` is `void *`, then the cast to `void *` is not needed.

Comment: the problem is that `resultData` is `void*&` which cannot be bound to a temporary, i.e. the result of `static_cast`

Comment: I solved this problem by creating `char *data = response.GetBuffer(response.GetLength());` and then releasing this buffer - that gives me copy of CString saved in data buffer. This is part of MFC API

Comment: @bolov: I think that the OP has it as a function parameter. Like `void function(void *&resultData) { }`

Comment: @drewpol: yeah, this seems a better solution. I'm not familiar with MFC, but maybe casting away `const` is against the design of the API. I've just strictly answered your original question, not mentioning whether it is a good idea or not. On the other hand, I cannot imagine any scenario, where casting away `const` doesn't work, if you: 1) actually don't modify resultData, and 2) don't modify CString while you use resultData. But even if it works, doesn't seem to be a good practice to follow.